# Test size of newest file

Tags: bash, test

I want to check if the size of the newest file is greater than 2 MB:

```
test $(ls -st | head -n2 | tail -n1 | awk '{print $1}') -gt 2097152 && echo "true"
```

**Is there a more efficient or elegant way to do this?**

I tried to further pipe the output of awk to

```
| test {} -gt 2097152
```

but get

> bash: test: {}: integer expression expected

Then

```
| test {}>"2097152"
```

yields always 'true' so I came up with the construct

```
test $(...) -gt 2097152
```

Comment: Note that `ls -s` doesn't report the size but the disk usage.

Answer (score 3):

There might be better ways than `ls` for getting the newest file, but most of what you do can be done just in awk:

```
ls -st | awk 'NR == 2 && $1 > 2097152 {print "true"}'
```

- `NR == 2` - in the second line
- `$1 > 2097152` - when the first column is greater than 2097152

Answer (score 3):

With `zsh`:

```
set -- *(.om[1]) *(N.L+2097152om[1])
if [[ $1 = $2 ]]; then
  printf '%s\n' "The apparent size of the newest non-hidden regular file in the current" \
                "directory ($1) is strictly greater than 2MiB."
fi
```

If you want to include hidden directories, add `D` to both glob qualifiers. If you want to consider non-regular files (directories, symlinks, devices...), remove `.`

The idea is to expand both these globs:

1. the list of non-hidden regular (`.`) files, `o`rdered by `m`odification time, limited to one (`[1]`).
2. the same but limited to files whose `L`ength is strictly greater (`+`) than `2097152` (but enabling `N`ullGlob so it's not a fatal error if there's no match).

And our condition is meant if both globs expand to the same file.

Note that `ls -s`, doesn't report the size of files but their disk usage (in number of 512-byte units, or KiB or other depending on the `ls` implementation and/or the environment). `ls` reports the file size in it *long* output format (`ls -l` or `ls -n` (or `-o`/`-g` with some implementations)).

Another option is to use `zsh`'s `stat` builtin to get the size (or disk usage) of the newest file:

```
zmodload zsh/stat
if
  stat -LH s -- *(.om[1]) &&
    ((s[size] > 2097152))
then
  printf '%s\n' "The apparent size of the newest non-hidden regular file in the current" \
                "directory ($1) is strictly greater than 2MiB."
fi
```

Or:

```
zmodload zsh/stat
if
  stat -LH s -- *(.om[1]) &&
    ((s[blocks] > 2097152))
then
  printf '%s\n' "The newest non-hidden regular file in the current directory" \
                "($1) uses more than 2097152 512-byte units of disk space."
fi
```

(in other words, its disk usage is more than 1GiB)